# No module named 'sklearn.datasets.samples_generator'

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, python-3.6

When trying to create 4 clusters of random data, I am getting the following error message:

```
# Generate 4 clusters of random data.
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs

data, _ = make_blobs(n_samples=300, centers=4,
                     cluster_std=0.60, random_state=0)
```

Error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-f93335003f84> in <module>
      1 # Generate 4 clusters of random data.
----> 2 from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
      3 
      4 data, _ = make_blobs(n_samples=300, centers=4,
      5                      cluster_std=0.60, random_state=0)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.datasets.samples_generator'
```

I have tried: `pip install sckit-learn` and `pip install sckit-datasets`

Answer (score 104, accepted):

In the latest versions of scikit-learn, there is no module `sklearn.datasets.samples_generator` - it has been replaced with `sklearn.datasets` (see the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.datasets)); so, according to the [`make_blobs` documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_blobs.html), your import should simply be:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
```

As a general rule, the official documentation is your best friend, and you should definitely consult it first before anything else.

Answer (score -1):

The `make_blobs` has been moved from `sklearn.datasets.samples_generator` to `sklearn.datasets` in the newer versions of `scikit-learn`.

If you still need to use `make_blobs` from `sklearn.datasets.samples_generator` then you need to use older versions of `scikit-learn`.

Answer (score -1):

this solved my problem

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

Comment: This is highly unlikely, as the code in question would work as is with *older* versions of scikit-learn, but not with newer ones; plus, similar attempts had already been tried by the OP, without success.